# How do I fix Chromebook touchscreen alignment?

Tags: display, chromebook, touchscreen, google-chrome-os

I have a Lenovo Chromebook Duet (10.1").

The touchscreen works, but it is not registering the touches in the right places.

For example, when I touch an app on my Chromebook, it will open the app 2 inches to the left.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Google recommends resetting Chrome. See https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2766492?hl=en and  https://www.lifewire.com/fix-non-working-touchscreen-on-chromebook-4845822,

Comment: If you have a solution then you should accept your answer. You may have to wait a day or so before you can but that is the preferred option rather than editing your question in the way that you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I powerwashed my Chromebook, and it seemed to fix the issue.